# How to add userControl (Add/Edit/Save/Delete/Search panel) in Windows Form(C#)

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am working on an application with multiple forms the users work with. I have created a usercontrol(only Design) with required buttons but I am not able to implement them as I need, I want that every form should have a functionality  to add, edit, update, delete, search and print and the user rights for each functionality should be manageable by an admin. 
I need help to start working.

Comment: Here is some more content to go through http://visualcsharptutorials.com/windows-forms

Comment: @yanguya995 thanks for the link but that link is for learning control not what i am looking for, i want to single usercontrol that can be used in n numbers of form, as can add separate add edit bottons for every form where i require it, but i want ot create a single control which can be implemented in several forms

Comment: I dont get what you looking for

Comment: k, well i am working

Comment: on a desktop application where i have created a   user control with multiple buttons Eg ADD EDIT SAVE DELETE SEARCH PRINT now i want to use this control in other forms and give them the event handlers and user right as per requirement as i got this idea from looking at several desktop application but i don't know how to implement it as per the form like it is done using separate button for ADD EDIT SAVE DELETE

Comment: Can you create share this on sime cliud drive where we can have a picture of what you want,